# PCIe Connectors Don't Match Up (?)

Tags: pci-express

I am trying to install a new VGA video card to my computer (a Dell Optiplex 380 mini-tower). This computer has a PCIe slot for add-in cards. I purchased a PCIe VGA video card on eBay but it doesn't fit the PCIe slot (the keyway and keyway slots don't match up - see picture below).
**I"m confused. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?**
I looked at several other cards on eBay and they all look like the lower image below (won't fit).

[image]

Comment: Care to provide more specifics?

Comment: Not sure what you’re confused about? The black slot is obviously the correct one. The other slots are PCI slots (+ some extension).

Comment: It looks like it would be a good idea to clear the dust from the slot before inserting the card - enthusiastic use of a "camera lens blower" should be helpful. (Don't use a vacuum cleaner as apparently they can create static electricity, which is bad for computers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The black slot is PCIe, the white slots are PCI (no "e").

You cannot fit a PCIe graphics card in the white slots.

To confirm, from the [Dell Optiplex Technical Manual](https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/Business_solutions_engineering-Docs_Documents/en/optiplex-380-tech-guide.pdf)

[image]

Your slot closest to the battery is the PCIe slot, the other two are PCI only.

Comment: I agree the bottom port is PCI 5v-only. The middle one looks like PCI with some appendix to the left. What is this? It doesn't resemble anything known to me. It's not the PCI-X, not the PCIe, what is it? Dell's proprietary crap?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov it is indeed odd, too short for 64-bit PCI and too long for "just" standard PCI. Maybe PCI and an additional power section for high power RAID cards or something?

Comment: @Ramhound https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/Business_solutions_engineering-Docs_Documents/en/optiplex-380-tech-guide.pdf page 7 shows both white connectors as PCI Slot. it might be that the extra section is power for the "combo riser" that can be used in the event the motherboard is installed in a low profile case.

Comment: @Mokubai You're right about the riser connector. Dell has been doing this on a number of models were the same motherboard is used in the low profile and the normal (or tower) case. HP and Lenovo have done it as well on some of their models.  And you have to be real careful about those risers. Even though they might physically fit in another model they are NOT always using the same pinout for the extension on the connector.

Comment: Duh. Brain cramp.